# In-app Purchase Windows 8 Recover

Tags: windows-8, in-app-purchase, restore, recover, winrt-async

I am developing for Windows 8 - Metro and  would like to know how I can restore or recover my purchases after reinstall the application.

Answer (score 0):

The server keeps a record of everything that a user has purchased in the Store.  An end user can open the Store app and press Windows+Z to open the App Bar.  There is a top app bar menu item called "Your apps".  Click that and you can see the apps you've purchased (select "all apps" from the dropdown if need be).  Reinstall the app, and verify that the in-app purchase is still enabled.

Comment: Hi Jennifer,

First of all, thanks for your answer. So, I don't want to restore the application, but its content.

For example, an newspaper application with  paid content. I've bought a paid content and sometime after I've reinstalled the newspaper application. There is a way to recover the content I've paid?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My in app purchase (remove ads) was restored with a new installation of the app. Try to reinstall.

Jan